# How will changing the splitting point in merge sort affect the algorithm and its time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

Everyone knows that merge sort will continuously divide the array into halves until they are small enough to (like 2 elements per block or so) be able to be sorted quickly, hence its time complexity being (n*log n). n part being the merge and log n being the splitting part of the algorithm.

But how would the algorithm change in terms of efficiency and time complexity if the "mid" point (where the array is split) isn't n/2. So for example, you decide to split the array in an 4:6 ratio or 3:7 ratio every split. How would this affect the algorithm.

Hypothetically, could the splitting part also be linear just like the merging part?

Comment: For a 3:7 split, you get the recurrence as $T(n) = 3T(n/10) + 7T(n/10) + n$ which is as good as $T(n) = 10T(n/10) + n$ which works out as $O(nlogn)$. The same holds for 4:6 split.

Comment: @RinkeshP A 3:7 split would give $T(n) = T(3n/10) + T(7n/10) + \mathcal{O}(n)$, not the formula you gave (although the result is still $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$).

Comment: Yeah that's right, thanks for correcting me.